# Downloaded Google big query data to Jupyter notebook but only 1000 rows captured

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, google-bigquery

I used following code:

query = """select * from  ZONE.STATE_MASTER_DATA WHERE TIME_KEY BETWEEN '2020-01-01' AND '2020-03-31'"""

webinar_data = gbq.read_gbq(query,project_id='Project1')

However only 1000 rows data is captured. In Google big query, number of rows is 401321.
How to capture all rows of data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is described in the Pandas [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/options.html) that in order to change the maximum number of rows which will be shown, you should use ***display.max_rows***.

After importing the pandas library, you can use the `set_options()` method to set the amount of rows in the output. Besides, you can also choose `None`, which will output all the rows in your dataset. Although, be careful using `None` because in case that you have a very large amount of rows, your Kernel might be busy for a while until it displays everything.

Below, there are some usage examples:

**1)** *Setting the maximum of rows to 3000 in the output*

```
import pandas as pd 
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 3000)
```

**2)** *Setting the maximum of rows to unlimited in the output*

```
 import pandas as pd
 pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
```

*In addition, I must point that the current default is 15 rows per output.*